# How to pass the autocomplete value if it is not one of the suggested results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, symfony1

I have managed to build a working autocomplete in symfony with the sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter like this :

```
$this->widgetSchema['expediteur'] = new sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter(array('url' => 'autocompleteExpediteur',
                       'config' => '{
                          scrollHeight: 300,
                          autoFill: false}'));
      $this->validatorSchema['expediteur'] = new sfValidatorPass();
```

It works fine if I choose one of the suggested results but if I try to enter a new value nothing gets passed to my action (simplified) :

```
protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()));

    echo($form->getValue('expediteur')):
}
```

I have looked through all the demos on : http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/ but have not found how to pass the value if it is not one of the suggested results.
I dont know if it is a jQuery / autocomplete or Symfony problem but any help would be mutch appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your AJAX Script called correctly, your can see it with the Firefox plugin firebug.
It seems you all the wrong URL ("autocompleteExpediteur"). Your URL-Parameter should be someting like "url_for('module/action')".